# Sticky slide menu using jquery

Tags: jquery

often many site developing sticky slide menu. the menu slide out from bottom right and when user click on close button it does not close rather it's size become small. menu has title always like "Recommended for you".

i was looking for this type of menu and search google for any jquery plug-in exist or not but found none. so here i am giving the url just go there and scroll down to bottom then a menu comes from bottom-right side. i just need that same type of menu. so tell me way to develop same one like it or if same kind of menu code already exist and if anyone aware of that then plzz share the site link.

[enter link description here](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/wordpress-theme-jquery-and-ajax/)

[enter link description here](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-set-focus-on-first-textbox-of.html)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, these are all the `iframe page`

they all use some plugin from `https://www.cloudflare.com/`

you can find from there.

**UPDATE:**

sorry for my careless. this time, I find it to you.

[see](http://simplereach.com)

[and documents](http://simplereach.com/docs/publisher/overview)